# how to send a message and wait for a reply in python, twilio in whatsapp

Tags: python, django, twilio, bots

I want to take the details of a person on whatsapp and store it but it seems its not working as I want it to. It's not waiting for the user to input the first data before the second one is coming.

This is my `models.py`:

```
class student_Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    place_of_stay = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and this is my `views.py`:

```
@csrf_exempt
def sms(request):
    incoming_msg = request.POST.get('Body', '').lower()
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    msg = resp.message()
    msg1 = resp.message()

    if 'hi' in incoming_msg:
        reply = ("Hello and welcome to kkk banking system WhatsApp bot!\n\n"
                "What would you like to do\n"
                "1. Create an accout?\n"
                "2. Check your account balance\n")

        msg.body(reply)


    if incoming_msg == '1':
        reply = ("Enter your name")
        a = incoming_msg
        student.name = a
        reply = ("Enter your place of stay")
        b = incoming_msg
        student.place_of_stay = b
        msg.body(reply)
        student.save()
        reply = ("Your details has been saved!!.")
        msg.body(reply)
```

Comment: i suggest you to use channels for real time communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every answer/response by your user via WhatsApp/SMS will be a new call to your `sms` method, i.e. you need to either **A)** split your logic to collect the data you need or **B)** let them enter it in one go.

Re **A)**: You could save the data in the session, a cache or your model to keep track whether the user has answered a question (e.g. identified by the user's phone number because this is submitted each time). You will need to find a way to identify the answers. Maybe with "*Enter your place of stay*" the user can only pick from a selected number of answers? Then you could do an `if` checking if the `incoming_msg` is one of those and otherwise it'll probably be an answer to the other question, e.g. pseudocode:

```
if incoming_msg == 'hi':
    # Show welcome message
    # return message
elif incoming_msg == '1':
    # Show first question
    # return message
elif incoming_msg in [<list of available places>]:
    # Retrieve current user from session/cache
    # Save place of stay
    # return message
else:
    # Save name
    # Update session/cache
    # Form second question
    # Return message
```

Re **B)**: You could let the user submit something like `<name> <place of stay>` in one go, e.g. `Joseph My place of stay` and then you split the answer in your business logic.